# SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(command) and IsNullable

Tags: sql-server, orm, sqlcommandbuilder

I have written an O/R database wrapper that generates some wrapper methods for stored procs it reads from the database.

Now I need to produce some custom wrapper code if an input parameter of a stored proc is defaulted to NULL. The problem is - I get stored proc parameters using:

```
SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(command)
```

and it doesn't bring parameter defaults. Is there any way to look up those defaults? Are they stored anywhere in the database?

BTW, I'm using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For T-SQL stored procedures, the only means to do this is to parse the procedure definition out of the `sys.sql_modules` table. From the BOL on the sys.parameters table regarding the `has_default_value` column:

> 1 = Parameter has default value.
>
> SQL Server only maintains default
>   values for CLR objects in this catalog
>   view; therefore, this column has a
>   value of 0 for Transact-SQL objects.
>   To view the default value of a
>   parameter in a Transact-SQL object,
>   query the definition column of the
>   sys.sql_modules catalog view, or use
>   the OBJECT_DEFINITION system function.

Here is an article to someone that wrote a T-SQL function that supposedly does just that: [Figure Out the Default Value of Stored Procedure Parameters.](http://dev.mainsoft.com/Default.aspx?tabid=181)

Comment: Thanks! I suspected that I would have to parse the proc definition to get the defaults, and I'm glad someone has already done it :)

Answer (score -1):

Basically, sqlcommandbuilder class automaticaly generates single table commands that are used to reconcile changes made to a dataset with the sql server.

Comment: This is not an answer. The question is: How to get procedure's parameter defaults?